# Rails manage the Versioning of table in mariadb 10.3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, mariadb

After Upgrading from MariaDB 10.2 to MariaDB 10.3, I change table `documents` with system versioning.

**MYSQL console :**

```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE documents \G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: documents
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `documents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `writing_content` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_locked` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=697 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING
```

From now, all updates will be saved in my database.

**My issue is :**

I don't want mariadb to store all versions for all sql like `update document set ...`

**My objective is :**

If the value of column `writing_content` isn't modified so there isn't new version generate in database.

example in rails app :

```
Document.find(1).update_attributes({is_locked:true}) #=> don't save with a new version
Document.find(1).update_attributes({writing_content:'test test'}) #=> will be saved with a new version
```

How to do this control in my controller ? Thank you for Any suggestions.

Env:
Ruby 2.4.1
Rails 5.1.6

Comment: Suggest moving to InnoDB (for other reasons).

Comment: @RickJames yes, I have done.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself :

**Excluding Columns From Versioning**

all others columns except `writing_contents` can be declared WITHOUT VERSIONING.

**CREATE a new table :**

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `documents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL WITHOUT SYSTEM VERSIONING,
  `writing_content` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_locked` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0 WITHOUT SYSTEM VERSIONING,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=697 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING
```

**Modify a existing table's column :**

```
SET @@system_versioning_alter_history = 1;
ALTER TABLE document MODIFY writing_content  WITH  SYSTEM VERSIONING;
```

[Know more](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/#system-variables)